# receive jquery progress bar value from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a problem with receiving value for progressbar from mysql.
My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>progressbar demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar"></div>

<script>
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 100 //<----- here i need to put value from mysql table
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping

i trying do something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_progress WHERE id = '1' 
$conn = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$progress = $row['progress'];
?>
```

and:

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $progress; ?>%;"><?php echo $progress; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Someone help me please!

Comment: looks like you haven't tried to query the database yet...

Comment: Please edit your post with your queries and PHP code, it will be a lot easier to help you if you do that, thanks

Comment: Put these comments in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest You to use jQuery `$.get()` method and use it like:

for example we have file named `progress_bar.php` and it's content:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_progress WHERE id = '1'"; 
$conn = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo json_encode(array('value' => $row['progress']));
?>
```

and page with a progressbar on it:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>

<script>
$.get('progress_bar.php',function(data){
var pb = $.parseJSON(data);    
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: pb.value });    
});
</script>
```

or if You want to pass `ID` to your `query` then use `$.post()` method and
in `progress_bar.php` make the following changes:

```
<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_progress WHERE id = '$id'";
```

and JS part:

```
 <script>
 $.post('progress_bar.php', { id: 1 }, function(data){
 var pb = $.parseJSON(data);    
 $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: pb.value });    
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php inside your script tag. PHP is executed before JS, so your javascript will have the value of `$progress`:

```
<script>
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: <?php echo $progress; ?>
});
</script>
```